# Copy project history with lots of branches to new SVN Repo

Tags: svn

I've got a repository with about 8 projects in it. One is being taken over by a new team and I want to copy its history. The old team had a convention of coding new features on a branch then merging them in; as a result the full history of the project is spread across about 130 branches. To extract the relevant history from the dump I used the command:

```
svndumpfilter include --pattern */OldProject/*.* ^
    --skip-missing-merge-sources --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs --quiet ^
    < full.dump > filtered.dump
```

I attempted to use the following to import:

```
svnadmin load NewProject --parent-dir import < filtered.dump
```

But I get an error

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 3
 * adding path : branches/Feature1/OldProject/Content/Picker.css 
 ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction '8-a', path
  'branches/Feature1/OldProject/Content/Picker.css'
```

I assume this can be resolved by adding the missing file, but I really don't want to have to do this for the entire project history. Do I have any options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the traffic and dearth of answers I assume there's no "easy" fix for this problem. While far from ideal our approach is to simply copy the project in it's current state to the new repo and include a readme instructing the user that older history can be found in the previous repository.